# Obtaining HIT Id while creating HIT in Amazon Mturk using Boto

Tags: python-2.7, boto, mechanicalturk

I'm working on a project in Amazon Mturk. Im using the Python Boto API .

The boto.connection.create_HIT() method returns an object of ResultSet from which I am trying to get the HIT Id . I also used Response Groups like 'HITDetail', HITAssignmentSummary' and 'HITQuestion' in the Create_HIT().

```
my_hit = mturk_connection.create_hit(hit_type = my_hit_type,
            question = my_question,
            max_assignments = 1,
            annotation = "An annotation from boto ",
            lifetime = 8*60, 
            response_groups = ['HITDetail','HITQuestion','HITAssignmentSummary'])
```

But I am not able to find a way to get the HIT Id from what it returns.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the create_HIT (), pass the value of the argument 'response_groups' as 'Minimal'.
Then in your case, use the my_hit[0].HITTypeId
It should work fine now.. :)